# May I delete exim4 files?

Tags: disk-space-utilization

I'm running out of inodes, I discovered that there are ~155000 files in var/spool/exim4/input - may I safely delete those files?

I found out that exim4 is some kind of emailer - but I believe I don't need it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost every *nix host needs a mailer - for system messaging.

You can remove the exim spool files, but it would be much better to investigate what was sent to you. I think those files are messages from `cron` about some problem(s).

For proper removal you have to enter the `/var/spool/exim4/msglog` and run:

```
exim -Mrm <filename>
```